# Get most recent date from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have two Tables

Table1:

```
    ______ID_______|_______serials______|____Date_____|__include__
          20       |         1123       |   22-05-2014|    yes
          20       |         2231       |   12-06-2013|    No
          21       |         3213       |   24-01-2014|    yes
          22       |         5123       |   27-10-2012|    yes
          20       |         1213       |   02-03-2014|    yes
```

Table 2:

```
   ______ID_______|______serials_______|____Date_____|__Rma__
          1       |         1123       |   01-05-2014|   1
          2       |         2231       |   22-06-2014|   7
          3       |         3353       |   20-01-2013|   5
          4       |         1213       |   27-03-2014|   2
          5       |         5123       |   06-03-2014|   9
```

I need a data of matched serials from two tables and need to pull recent date from two tables.
This is how I am expecting output

```
_____ID_______|_______serials______|__RecentDate_|__include__|__ID__|__serial__|__Rma__
     20       |         1123       |   22-05-2014|    yes    |  1   |  1123    |   1
     20       |         2231       |   22-06-2014|    No     |  2   |  2231    |   7
     20       |         1213       |   27-03-2014|    yes    |  4   |  1213    |   2
     22       |         5123       |   06-03-2014|    yes    |  5   |  5123    |   9
```

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  t1.id, t1.serials,
        CASE WHEN t1.date > t2.date THEN t1.date ELSE t2.date END recentDate,
        t1.include, t2.id, t2.serials, t2.rma
FROM    table1 t1
JOIN    table2 t2
ON      t2.serials = t1.serials
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic sql for simple join or inner join.

```
select * 
from table_1 a, table_2 b
where a.serials = b.serials;
```

To get the recent try using `order by`

```
select * 
from table_1 a, table_2 b
where a.serials = b.serials
order by a.date;
```

Comment: How can I get Most recent Date with this

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t.id,serials,s.Date,include,t1.id,t1.serials
from table1 t
join table2 t1
on t.serials = t1.serials
join(

Select Serials,max(Date) 'date'
from (
        Select Serials ,DATE
        from table1 
        union all 
        Select Serials ,DATE
        from table2 

        )
group by serials        
) s on t.serials = s.serials
```